# Returning a typed Func as a generic Func

Tags: c#, generics

I have multiple implementations of a data source interface.
It has one method CanGet used to discover if it can source a particular type and then another Get used to execute it.
I am trying to code this specific implementation as such but it does like passing GetCostLedger back from the FindSource because the types do no not match. I can not see how to get this to work.
Thanks for any help.

```
private Func<IEnumerable<T>> FindSource<T>() where T : class
{
    if (typeof(CostLedger).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return GetCostLedger;

    if (typeof(EquipmentInventory).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return GetEquipmentInventory;

    if (typeof(ActivePavingJobs).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return GetActivePavingJobs;

    return null;
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class
{
    var source = FindSource<T>();
    if (source != null)
        return source.Invoke();

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public bool CanGet<T>() where T : class
{
    return FindSource<T>() != null;
}

private IEnumerable<CostLedger> GetCostLedger()
{
    //Implementation clipped
}

private IEnumerable<EquipmentInventory> GetEquipmentInventory()
{
    //Implementation clipped
}

private IEnumerable<ActivePavingJobs> GetActivePavingJobs()
{
    //Implementation clipped
}
```

The use case for this code is in an ETL process that runs a lot of transformations
The data sources are called from a factory with the implementations injected like so

```
_destination.SaveData(
    _mapper.Find<IEnumerable<CostLedger>, LaborAndEquipmentAnalysis>()
               .Process(_source.First(x => x.CanGet<CostLedger>())
    .GetData<CostLedger>(), dashboardName, DateTime.UtcNow));
```

Comment: Clarified my examples to help with confusion on why I am doing what I am doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is most certainly not the way to do it, but if you must....

```
private Func<IEnumerable<T>> FindSource<T>() where T : class
{
    if (typeof(CostLedger).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return ()=>GetCostLedger ().Cast<T> ();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter... reading between the lines, it looks like this is actually a `protected override` of a generic base class method.  If you don't like the answer, at least explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an open generic type in this method

```
private Func<IEnumerable<T>> FindSource<T>() where T : class {
    if (typeof(CostLedger).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        return GetCostLedger;

    return null;
}
```

if you are returning a closed generic type?

That is, why are you letting this method work for all `T` where `T` is a reference type if you are actually using it when `T` is `CostLedger`?

At a minimum, if all you ever want is `CostLedger` and its derived types, you should say

```
private Func<IEnumerable<T>> FindSource<T>() where T : CostLedger
```

But really, I don't see why you don't just say

```
private Func<IEnumerable<CostLedger>> FindSource()
```

if all you are using for `T` is `CostLedger`.

Comment: CostLedger is my example but its not the only one I return, I have multiple implementations of the data source interface and each can fulfill only certain types. It is up to each implementation to say which they can handle.

Comment: Your method body says `CostLedger` is the only type you are using.